# keyPressEvent is not working in my PyQt application

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I am trying to use keyPressEvent in a mainwindow I generated with QtDesigner but no key press is detected by my program. Here is my code
The QtDesigner generated class is MainWindowUI.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow,MainWindowUI.Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, translator,parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        #super(MainWindow,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.translator=translator
        self.completeGUI()


    def completeGUI(self):
        self.setConnections()
        self.set_line_edit_validators()
        self.category_combo.insertSeparator(4)
        self.category_combo.insertSeparator(8)
        self.type_conjug_combo.insertSeparator(3)
        self.type_conjug_combo.insertSeparator(6)
        #self.type_conjug_combo.setItemData( 0, QtGui.QColor('red'), QtCore.Qt.ForegroundRole )
        self.save_button.clicked.connect(self.fileSave)
        self.category_label.hide()
        self.category_combo.hide()
        self.type_conjug_label.hide()
        self.type_conjug_combo.hide()
        self.grammar_combo.setStyleSheet("color:red")
        self.category_combo.setStyleSheet("color:red;")
        self.type_conjug_combo.setStyleSheet("color:red;")
        self.palat_combo.setStyleSheet("color:red;")
        self.accent_combo.setStyleSheet("color:red;")
        self.terme_edit.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid red;")
        print("completeGUI is over")

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        print(e.key())
```

I had a look at various answers to analog question on this forum but I could not manage to have it working.
Thank you for help.

HERE IS A MINIMAL EXAMPLE THAT REPRODUCES THE TROUBLE

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import sys
from view.NewMainWindow import NewMainWindow



if __name__=='__main__':
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        translator = QtCore.QTranslator()

        app.installTranslator(translator)
        mainWindow = NewMainWindow(translator)
        NewMainWindow.show(mainWindow)
        #sys.exit(app.exec_())
        current_exit_code=app.exec_()
        app=None
```

AND THE NEWMAINWINDOW

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import  QMainWindow
from gen import NewMainWindowUI 


class NewMainWindow(QMainWindow,NewMainWindowUI.Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self,translator, parent=None):
        super(NewMainWindow,self).__init__(parent)       
        self.setupUi(self)
        print('init completed')

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        print('event detected')
        print(e.key())
```

THE GENERATED INTERFACE

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'src/designer/newmainwindow.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.13.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 110, 113, 36))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 29))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: When overloading `keyPressEvent` you still need to return `super().keyPressEvent(e)`. This is probably not related to your real issue but like this it can not work at all.

Comment: @TimKörner that doesn't have anything to do with `super`, and that's because the problem's source is conceptual: calling `super().keyPressEvent(event)` wouldn't change anything, since the problem is that the QMainWindow's keyPressEvent method is *not* being called in the first place, probably because the central widget (or the platform "plugin") consumes it.

Comment: @eyllanesc please see minimal reproducible example. Only the return key triggers an event.

Comment: @meaulnes your edit is *not* a reproducible example: it requires the `NewMainWindowUI.Ui_MainWindow` class imported from `gen`, which you didn't provide.

Comment: @musicamante, i am sorry. I just added it.

Answer (score 1):

I usually avoid calling a `keyPressEvent` from both the central widget and the main window, because, as @musicamante said, one could be "consuming" the other. Especially if you plan on switching between multiple central widgets.

You should instead create a slot on a `QMainWindow` object connected to the central widget's `keyPressEvent` (but name it something else, like `onKeyPressEvent` or something) and then you emit the event from inside the MainWindow's `keyPressEvent`, something like this:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeyEvent


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    key_pressed = pyqtSignal(QKeyEvent)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        central_widget = NewWindow()
        self.key_pressed.connect(central_widget.onKeyPressEvent)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        ...

    def keyPressEvent(self, event: QKeyEvent) -> None:
        self.key_pressed.emit(event)
        return super().keyPressEvent(event)


class NewWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ...

    @pyqtSlot(QKeyEvent)
    def onKeyPressEvent(self, event: QKeyEvent) -> None:
        print(event.key())
        return
```